# Cannot get specific div option

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm building a very simple scraping that should take all the countries available on this [website](https://uk.soccerway.com/). The countries are available inside the "Club Domestic" dropdown.

For take the coutnries, I'm using `Nodejs` with `cheerio` (I don't know if that library is a good  choice, I'm a very beginner on that).

This is my code:

```
const request = require('request');

var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var cheerioAdv = require('cheerio-advanced-selectors');

request('https://uk.soccerway.com/', function(err, resp, html)
{
  if (!err)
  {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var countriesMenu = cheerioAdv.find($, '#navbar-left > div:eq(2)');

    $(countriesMenu).each(function()
    {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
  }
});
```

essentially I declared a constant called `request` which perform all the request `GET`. Then I declared other two variable one that contains the library `cheerio` and another called `cheerioAdv` and should allow me to accomplish this task.

The `cheerio advanced selector` should allow me to access to specific tag position.

Based on that explaination, I saved the content of the second div of `navbar-left` which contains all the options countries that I want.

When I start the script using: `node app.js` nothing is printed. I also tried to add `options` after `eq(2)`, what I did wrong?

Comment: I think `eq` should be used like this https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#eq-i-

Comment: @null I tried using `var countriesMenu = $('#navbar-left > div option').eq(1);` no iteration..

Comment: try `$('#navbar-left').eq(1)` and see what you get.

Comment: You need to "view source" to see what's really there, if you're going by the inspector you will be seeing something other than what cheerio sees.

Answer (score 0):

The `request` module didn't actually contain `#navbar-left`. if you try to `console.log(html)` you will notice that the html data is a bit odd. That's because request module can only render initial html body and not javascript rendered data such as ajax or react/ angular. Try to use other modules other than `request`.  Perhaps use a headless browser instead. `Nightmare` is a great one.

```
npm install nightmare --save
```

You make a call using nightmare instance then pass the html code to your cheerio. Here is the sample:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

nightmare
    .goto(url)

    //do something in the chain to go to your desired page.

   .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('html').outerHTML) // html selector

   .then(function (html) {
      cheerio.load(html);
      // DO SOMETHING IN CHEERIO HERE

    )
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```